# Replace column values based on another dataframe python pandas? (beginner)

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have  2 dataframes.

In df1 I have a lot of NaN which I want to substitute by values in df2. The number of values in df2 is the same of number of NaN in df1.

I have tried to join, merge and create cycle, but without success.

Thanks in advance!

```
pd.Dataframe 1
0          NaN
1        240.0
2        229.0
3       1084.0
4       2078.0
        ....
Name: Healthcare_1, Length: 9999, dtype: float64

pd.Dataframe 2
0        830.0
6        100.0
7        100.0
8        830.0
9       1046.0
         ...  
Name: Healthcare_1, Length: 4797, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

In my answer I assume that the rows where the NANs occur in DataFrame1 have the same index as the rows in DataFrame2 that need to substitute these NANs.

Load the following modules:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
```

We have two example DataFrames:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'c1': [np.nan, 240, np.nan, 1084, 2078]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'c1': [830, 100, 100, 830, 1046]}, index=[0,2,7,8,9])
```

Determine the indices where NANs occur in df1:

```
ind = list(np.where(df1['c1'].isnull()))[0]
```

Check where these indices occur in df2. This should give *array([ True, True, False, False, False])*:

```
df2.index.isin(list(ind))
```

Replace the values from df1 with the values from df2 at the index `ind`:

```
df1[df1.index.isin(ind)] = df2[df2.index.isin(ind)]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1**: Use [.update()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html) to replace nan values in df1 by the corresponding value in df2:

```
df1 = pd.Series([np.nan, 240, 229, 1084, 2078])
df2 = pd.Series([830, 100, 100, 830, 1046], index=[0, 6, 7, 8, 9])

df1.update(df2)
```

**Solution 2**: You can also use [.combine_first()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.combine_first.html) to fill up the np.nan values of the first dataframe with the values of the second dataframe:

```
df1.combine_first(df2).iloc[df1.index]
```

**Resulting dataframe:**

```
    0
0   830.0
1   240.0
2   229.0
3   1084.0
4   2078.0
```

Comment: Thanks. Used data.loc[data['Healthcare_1'].index.isin(y_pred_HC1_NaN.index), ['Healthcare_1']] = y_pred_HC1_NaN['Healthcare_1']